# Google Tag Manager / Enhanced E-commerce - Purchase tag dataLayer push working only on Tag Assistance

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm trying to add Enhance Ecommerce but something isn't okay. When I make an order through Google Tag Assistance everything is working and the transaction is showed on the Google Analytics but when I make an order normally like customer nothing is showed.

This is what I've added to thank-you page on the shop

```
<script type="text/javascript">

dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'transaction',
    'ecommerce': {        
        'purchase': {
            'actionField': {
                'id': '<?php echo $order->get_order_number() ?>',
                'revenue': '<?php echo number_format($order->get_subtotal(), 2, ".", ""); ?>', 
                'number_of_products': '<?php echo $order->get_item_count(); ?>'
            },
            'products': [
                
                <?php foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $item): ?>
                {
                    'name': '<?php echo $item['name']; ?>',
                    'id': '<?php echo $item['product_id']; ?>',
                    'price': '<?php echo number_format($item->get_total(), 2, ".", ""); ?>',
                    'quantity': '<?php echo $item['qty']; ?>'
                },
                <?php endforeach; 
                ?>
            ]
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

And this is my setup in Google Tag Manager

tag
[image]

The trigger
[image]

Few variables - order_id
[image]

Product name
[image]

Tried google, tried tutorials and still nothing helped.

When I run from Tag Assistant everything is go to analytic. When doesn't go through Tag Assistant nothing is showed.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: GTM Workspace preview

[image]

Comment: You said "nothing is showed". Elaborate.

Comment: @BNazaruk, means I don't see any order on the Google Analytic. The order is successful on the shop but not showed on GA. When I make order through Tag Assistant I can see it on GA under enhanced ecommerce tab

Comment: When you're testing your preview, do you preview an empty workspace? Make a screenshot of your workspace's Overview.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure if I understand you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to enter preview, you have to first open GTM. In GTM, you have workspaces. Or at least, the default one. open GTM, go to the overview tab of the workspace that you're previewing (since you don't know what worspaces are, you probably use the default one) and make sure there are no Workspace Changes in it. Here is a screenshot of a workspace WITH changes:

[image]

And here is another workspace with NO changes:

[image]

If you have changes in your workspace, try publishing them and see if your tags start firing in prod.

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshot of the workspace. I have changes there but I believe they are already published. If they aren't published they should not fire even on Tag Assistant, right?

Comment: You were right! First time working with GTM and I though that the changes are automatically set after saving. Didn't knew that I need to actually publish them. After I published the changed and created a new version orders are coming on GA now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, all changes in the overview can be understood as deviations from whatever is in production. It's not always like that, but almost always in trivial setups. Glad I guessed correctly.